# Why CPU of server hosts Kentico web application get 100% utilization when bind it on my my host name www.xxx.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, cpu-usage, kentico

I have problem with my web application hosted in Kentico CMS.

1-When i Edit binding of my web application to be "xxx.net" the web application is reachable and cpu usage are range from 1 to 10 % and that's ok .
2-When i Edit binding "www.xxx.net" the web application hangs all the server and become unreachable and cpu usage goes high to be from 95 to 100 % .

3-This scenario has been tested on two servers with the same results above.
4-I have created simple web app contain simple HTML that binds to www.xxx.net and works.

Note that my web application uses Google Bot and i have disable it in rebots.txt and removed www.xxx.com from google webmaster tools.

Also i have used DebugDiag1.2 and generated report here is sample of what i have found of top 5 threads By CPU time..

```
.NET Threads Summary
ThreadCount:      37
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 21
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       16
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                           PreEmptive                                                   Lock
       ID  OSID        ThreadOBJ     State GC       GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
  11    1 22130 0000000002434e40      8220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
  25    2 22274 0000000002452a00      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Finalizer)
  27    3 22320 00000000024b3780   100a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  28    4 2243c 00000000024c4640      1220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
  29    7 224b0 000000000251a080   8009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port)
  15    6 26620 0000000002526340   8008220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port)
XXXX    8       0000000002544630     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX    9       0000000005934100   1019820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    a       0000000005956b00     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX    e       0000000005a124c0     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX    f       00000000059c0230     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   14       0000000006b3ea20     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   15       0000000006b3f130     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   17       0000000006b3ff50     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   19       0000000006b40d70     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   1a       0000000006b41480     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   1b       0000000006b41b90     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   1c       0000000006b422a0     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   1e       0000000006b430c0     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   20       0000000006b43ee0     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
   7   2d 265a8 0000000006be0b00       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
   8   2e 21e1c 0000000006be1210       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   30       0000000005c78090     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
XXXX   31       0000000005c787a0     19820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
  30    5 24050 0000000005c78eb0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  31   35 24214 0000000005c7aaf0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  10   40 265b0 0000000005c8b5d0       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
   3   41 26540 0000000005c0db30       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
  32   44 19df0 0000000005c0f060   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  33   45 1ea94 0000000005c0f770   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  34   46  2298 0000000005c0fe80   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  35   47  1ff8 0000000005c10590       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
  36   4a  93ac 0000000005c8a0a0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  39   4c 19a68 0000000005b6e9a0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  38   4d 14794 0000000005b6f7c0   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  40   50 123bc 0000000006beac30   1009220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
  41   4f  d1e8 0000000006beb340       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000002402fa0     0 Ukn
Thread report
Thread 0 - System ID 156876
Entry point   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
Create time   6/17/2014 12:48:02 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.00
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.031


This thread is incomplete and also has/have an invalid Thread Environment Block pointer. As a result, the information reported is most likely inaccurate.
Function      Source
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+a     
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+79   
w3wphost!AppHostInitialize+278    
w3wp!wmain+470    
w3wp!PerfStopProvider+19b     
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

**And one of the Threads :**

```
Thread 11 - System ID 139568
Entry point   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
Create time   6/17/2014 12:48:02 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.280
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.202


This thread is incomplete and also has/have an invalid Thread Environment Block pointer. As a result, the information reported is most likely inaccurate.

.NET Call Stack
Function

Full Call Stack
Function      Source
ntdll!NtRemoveIoCompletion+a      
KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus+39   
kernel32!GetQueuedCompletionStatusStub+11     
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+3b    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread+34    
w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread+61   
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

Answer (score 3):

Too me it seems like the application is getting into some kind of loop. I would try to search for some custom code, setting or handler mapping which may be related to the the www.xxx.net domain.

Comment: so why the same code works when i bind on xxx.net and when add www.xxx.net utilization reach 100%

Comment: There could be some conditional behavior. Is it possible you have some URL rewriting rule which goes against Kentico settings? Try to look at "Process domain prefix" setting in Kentico administration.

Comment: @MinaNabil it must be a loop: have you checked the: Domain Aliases Settings (sitemanager)? is the site running under https? checked the iis settings?